# Is it possible to get the password enabled flag on AWS iam user from the SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-iam

I am using the AWS java sdk, and would like to get the password enabled flag.
There is a way to get password last used date as seen below.  From the AWS web console, I can enable/disable the password for a user.

```
AmazonIdentityManagement iam = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(credential);
User userA = iam.listUsers().getUsers().find { it -> it.userName == "passwordEnabledNeverLoggedIn"}

println userA.passwordLastUsed  //  this prints null

// println userA.passwordEnabled -> would love this method, but it doesn't exist
```